# convert byte string tensor into plain string tensor in python tensorflow

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert a byte string tensor into string tensor so that I can perform few operations on string and store changed string back to same byte tensor in tensorflow 2.3

```
tf.Tensor([b"This is my first string as byte string,  b"This is my second string as byte string"'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

I used *tf.strings.as_string(a)* here 'a' is the input tensor but it gives me error

*InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of string is not in the list of allowed values: int8, int16, int32, int64....*

This is because *as_string* only accepts few input types only and I am passing bytes string.

How can I do it, please help as I am stuck on it

Answer (score -1):

b"This is my first string as byte string“ Is **bytes** type,
But your use dtype is **tf.string**

You can use Unicode string:

```
tf.Tensor([u"This is my first string as byte string,  u"This is my second string as byte string"], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

Comment: Thanks Timur. Let me explain it bit more. bascially I am reading few text files(having plain text) into a varialble using following code

Comment: Thanks Timur. bascially I am reading few text files(having plain text) into a var using following code `raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory('aclImdb/train',batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.99,subset='training')` from this article [https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification]. so in raw_train_ds we have got plain text in form of byte text tensors. Now I want to iterate over this dataset and remove stopwords from strings(byte strings), how can I itereate and perform stopwords replacement in this dataset

Comment: Keras methods with string may read at: https://www.amazon.com/Deep-Learning-Python-Francois-Chollet/dp/1617294438 - ISBN 978-1617294433 - chapter VI. It’s very positive book.